# could not find function "scaling_UV"

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm attempting to scale a dataset by its unit variance using the scaling_UV() function in R from the santaR package. I have installed and loaded the santaR library but I am still being told that the scaling_UV() function could not be found.

How can I use this function or is there another function that performs the same operation? I will even perform the scaling manually if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already used `library(santaR)` without errors.

If the function is exported by the package, `santaR::scaling_UV()` should work.
You can also try `santar:::scaling_UV()` (notice the three colons).

According to [the documentation](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/santaR/santaR.pdf), the function should be present in version `1.2.3`

Comment: first one didn't work but the second one did, thank you!